# how to map memory as USWC under windows/linux?

Tags: memory, assembly

I need to map most of the computer memory as uswc to take advantage of non-caching movntdqa. Is there any easy way to do this under windows or linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux, this is easy - although you'll have to be careful that you don't map kernel memory to W/C - that could get ugly.   Assuming you know how to reserve a physical range of memory from userspace, you can then use "/proc/mtrr" to change the memory type.

One example page describing the interface is [here](http://www.tikirobot.net/wp/2009/03/01/fixing-mtrrs-on-linux/)

Comment: makes sense. i just need to find out how todo it in windows - see separate question.