# Intel-64 and ia32 atomic operations acquire-release semantics and GCC 5+

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, atomic, futex

I am investigating Intel CPU atomic features on my Haswell CPU 
(a 4/8 core 2.3-3.9ghz i7-4790M), and am finding it really hard
to construct eg. reliable mutex_lock() and mutex_unlock()
operations as suggested by for instance the GCC manual:

## 6.53 x86-Specific Memory Model Extensions for Transactional Memory

The x86 architecture supports additional memory ordering flags to mark
lock critical sections for hardware lock elision.  These must be
specified in addition to an existing memory model to atomic intrinsics.

```
 '__ATOMIC_HLE_ACQUIRE'
 Start lock elision on a lock variable.  Memory model must be
 '__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE' or stronger.
 '__ATOMIC_HLE_RELEASE'
 End lock elision on a lock variable.  Memory model must be
 '__ATOMIC_RELEASE' or stronger.
```

When a lock acquire fails it is required for good performance to abort
  the transaction quickly.  This can be done with a '_mm_pause'

```
 #include <immintrin.h> // For _mm_pause

 int lockvar;

 /* Acquire lock with lock elision */
 while (__atomic_exchange_n(&lockvar, 1, 
     __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE|__ATOMIC_HLE_ACQUIRE))
     _mm_pause(); /* Abort failed transaction */
 ...
 /* Free lock with lock elision */
 __atomic_store_n(&lockvar, 0, __ATOMIC_RELEASE|__ATOMIC_HLE_RELEASE);
```

So, reading that and the Intel Software Developer's Manual Vol.3 section
8.1, "Locked Atomic Operations", particulary section 8.1.4, 
"Effects of a LOCK Operation on Internal Processor Caches", 
led me to implement my test mutex_lock() mutex_unlock() at first
like:

`...
   static inline attribute((always_inline,const))
   bool ia64_has_clflush(void)
   { register unsigned int
     ebx=0;
     asm volatile
     ( "MOV $7, %%eax\n\t"
       "MOV $0, %%ecx\n\t"
       "CPUID\n\t"
       "MOV %%ebx,  %0\n\t"
     : "=r"                (ebx) :
     : "%eax", "%ecx", "%ebx"
     );
     return ((ebx & (1U<<23)) ? true : false);
    }`

```
#define _LD_SEQ_CST_ __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST
#define _ST_SEQ_CST_ __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST
#define _ACQ_SEQ_CST_ (__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST|__ATOMIC_HLE_ACQUIRE)
#define _REL_SEQ_CST_ (__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST|__ATOMIC_HLE_RELEASE)

static bool has_clflush=false;
static
void init_has_clflush(void)
{ has_clflush = ia64_has_clflush();
}
static
void init_has_clflush(void) __attribute__((constructor));

static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
void mutex_lock( register _Atomic int *ua )
{ // the SDM states that memory to be used as semaphores
  // should not be in the WB cache memory, but nearest we
  // can get to uncached memory is to explicitly un-cache it:
  if(has_clflush)
    asm volatile
    ( "CLFLUSHOPT (%0)"
      :: "r" (ua)
    );
    // why isn't the cache flush enough?
    else
      asm volatile
      ( "LFENCE" :: );
      register unsigned int x;
      x = __atomic_sub_fetch( ua, 1, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_);
      _mm_pause();
    if(has_clflush)
      asm volatile
      ( "CLFLUSHOPT (%0)"
       :: "r" (ua)
      );
    else
      asm volatile
      ( "SFENCE" :: );
  while((x = __atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_CST_)) != 0)
    switch(syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAIT, x, nullptr,nullptr,0))
    {case 0:
      break;
     case -1:
      switch( errno )
      { case EINTR:
        case EAGAIN:
         continue;
        default:
         fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected futex error: %d : '%s'.", errno,   
              strerror(errno));
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
  void mutex_unlock( register _Atomic int *ua )
  { if(has_clflush)
      asm volatile
      ( "CLFLUSHOPT (%0)"
      :: "r" (ua)
      );
    else
      asm volatile( "LFENCE" :: );
    register unsigned int x;
    x = __atomic_add_fetch( ua, 1, _REL_SEQ_CST_);
    _mm_pause();
    if(has_clflush)
      asm volatile
      ( "CLFLUSHOPT (%0)"
        :: "r" (ua)
      );
    else
      asm volatile ( "SFENCE" :: );
    if(x == 0)
      while( (1 < syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAKE, 1,
           nullptr,nullptr,0)) && (errno == EINTR));
  }
```

Now, what is interesting is that the critical mutex_lock() subtraction and
mutex_unlock() addition operations end up as the instructions:

mutex_lock:

```
# 61 "intel_lock1.c" 1
    CLFLUSHOPT (%rbx)
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
.L7:
    lock xacquire subl  $1, lck(%rip)
    rep nop
    cmpb    $0, has_clflush(%rip)
    je  .L8
#APP
# 72 "intel_lock1.c" 1
    CLFLUSHOPT (%rbx)
# 0 "" 2
```

mutex_unlock:

```
#APP
# 98 "intel_lock1.c" 1
    CLFLUSHOPT (%rbx)
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
.L24:
    movl    $1, %eax
    lock xacquire xaddl %eax, lck(%rip)
    rep nop
    addl    $1, %eax
    cmpb    $0, has_clflush(%rip)
    je  .L25
#APP
# 109 "intel_lock1.c" 1
    CLFLUSHOPT (%rbx)
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
```

But this implementation seems to require the LFENCE / SFENCE
to function reliably (CLFLUSHOPT is not enough) , otherwise 
both threads can end up deadlocked in futex() with 
the lock value being an identical -1 .

I cannot see from reading the intel documentation how it
can happen that two threads entering the instruction 
sequence :

```
# %rbx == $lck
CLFLUSHOPT (%rbx)
lock xacquire subl  $1, lck(%rip)
rep nop
```

can both end up with the result '-1' in *lck if *lck was 0 ;
surely one thread MUST get -1 and the other -2 ?

But strace says not:

```
strace: Process 11978 attached with 2 threads
[pid 11979] futex(0x60209c, FUTEX_WAIT, 4294967295, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 11978] futex(0x60209c, FUTEX_WAIT, 4294967295, NULL^C
```

this is the deadlock situation. Where did I go wrong ?

Please can any Intel CPU Locking & Caching experts out there explain
how two atomic decrements or increments of the same uncached location *lck
that both 
assert the #LOCK bus signal (exclusive bus access) and XACQUIRE
can end up getting the same result in *lck?

I thought that was what the #LOCK prefix (and HLE) was meant to prevent ?
I have tried NOT using HLE and just __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST for all accesses, 
(this just adds the LOCK prefix, not XACQUIRE) but it makes no difference -
deadlock still results without the {L,S}FENCE-es.

I have read Ulrich Drepper's excellent paper [ Futexes are Tricky ] :http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/futex.pdf , but he presents
a mutex implementation that only writes hard-coded constants to
the lock memory . I can see why . It is very hard to 
get a mutex to work reliably with a waiter count or any
kind of arithmetic done on the lock value.
Has anyone found ways to do reliable locked arithmetic
such that the result is suitable for lock / semaphore
value on x86_64 Linux ? Most interested in discussing them ...

So after a few blind alleys investigating HLE & CLFLUSH, 
the ONLY working version of the lock / unlock I've been able to
arrive at uses hard coded constants and __atomic_compare_exchange_n -
the full source of the test program, which increments a counter
(without locking) until + / an exit signal is received,
is at:

## Working Example: intel_lock3.c

[]:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ElB0qmwcDMxy9NBYkSXVxljj5djITYxa

```
enum LockStatus
{ LOCKED_ONE_WAITER = -1
, LOCKED_NO_WAITERS = 0
, UNLOCKED=1
};

static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
bool mutex_lock( register _Atomic int *ua )
{ register int x;
  int cx;
 lock_superceded:
  x  = __atomic_load_n( ua, _LD_SEQ_CST_ );
  cx = x;
  x = (x == UNLOCKED)
       ? LOCKED_NO_WAITERS
       : LOCKED_ONE_WAITER;
  if (! __atomic_compare_exchange_n
      ( ua, &cx, x, false, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_,  _ACQ_SEQ_CST_) )
    goto lock_superceded;
  if( x == LOCKED_ONE_WAITER )
  { do{
    switch(syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAIT, x, nullptr,nullptr,0))
    {case 0:
      break;
     case -1:
      switch( errno )
      { case EINTR:
         return false;
        case EAGAIN:
          break;
        default:
          fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected futex WAIT error: %d : '%s'.",
                  errno, strerror(errno));
          return false;
       }
    }
    x = __atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_CST_);
    } while(x < 0);
  }
  return true;
}

static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
bool mutex_unlock( register _Atomic int *ua )
{ register int x;
  int cx;
 unlock_superceded:
  x  = __atomic_load_n( ua, _LD_SEQ_CST_ );
  cx = x;
  x = (x == LOCKED_ONE_WAITER)
       ? LOCKED_NO_WAITERS
       : UNLOCKED;
  if (! __atomic_compare_exchange_n
       ( ua, &cx, x, false, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_,  _ACQ_SEQ_CST_) )
    goto unlock_superceded;
    if(x == LOCKED_NO_WAITERS)
    { while((1 < 
             syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, nullptr,nullptr,0))
         ||( UNLOCKED != __atomic_load_n( ua, _LD_SEQ_CST_ ))
         ) // we were a waiter, so wait for locker to unlock !
      { if( errno != 0 )
          switch(errno)
          {case EINTR:
            return false;
           case EAGAIN:
            break;
           default:
            fprintf(stderr,
                  "Unexpected futex WAKE error: %d : '%s'.", 
                  errno, strerror(errno));
            return false;
          }
      }
   }
   return true;
 }

 Build & Test (GCC 7.3.1 & 6.4.1 & 5.4.0) used:
 $ gcc -std=gnu11 -march=x86-64 -mtune=native -D_REENTRANT \
   -pthread -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o intel_lock3 intel_lock3.c

 $ ./intel_lock3
 # wait a couple of seconds and press ^C
 ^C59362558
```

## Broken Version Using Arithmetic:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=10yLrohdKLZT4p3G1icFHdjF5eHY68Yws

Compile with eg:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu11 -march=x86_64 -mtune=native -O3 -Wall -Wextra 
  -o intel_lock2 intel_lock2.c
$ ./intel_lock2
# wait a couple of seconds and press ^C
$ ./intel_lock2
^Cwas locked!
446
```

It should not be printing "was locked!" and within
a couple of seconds should have exceeded a count, printed
at the end,  of @ 5e8 : 5x10^8  , not 446.

Running with strace shows that two threads are blocking
waiting for the lock value of -1 to become 0 :

```
$ strace -f -e trace=futex ./intel_lock2
strace: Process 14481 attached
[pid 14480] futex(0x602098, FUTEX_WAIT, 4294967295, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 14481] futex(0x602098, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 14480] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily
                                          unavailable)
[pid 14481] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 14480] futex(0x602098, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 14481] futex(0x602098, FUTEX_WAIT, 4294967295, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 14480] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 14481] <... futex resumed> )       = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily
                                          unavailable)
[pid 14480] futex(0x602098, FUTEX_WAIT, 4294967295, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 14481] futex(0x602098, FUTEX_WAIT, 4294967295, NULL^C <unfinished  
...>
[pid 14480] <... futex resumed> )       = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted 
if SA_RESTART is set)
strace: Process 14480 detached
strace: Process 14481 detached
was locked!
7086
```

$

Normally, the WAIT should be scheduled before the WAKE, but somehow
GCC is interpreting the memory ordering semantics to mean that the
WAKE is always getting scheduled before any WAIT ; but even if that
happens, the code should just get delayed, and should never end up
with two threads getting a -1 lck value on entry to futex(...FUTEX_WAIT..).

The almost identical algorithm using arithmetic on the lock value ALWAYS
deadlocks when both threads get (-1,-1) - note, a -2 value is never seen
by any thread:

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
bool mutex_lock( register _Atomic volatile int *ua )
{ register int x;
  x = __atomic_add_fetch( ua, -1, _ACQ_SEQ_);
  if( x < 0 )
  { do{
    // here you can put:
    // if( x == -2) { .. NEVER REACHED! }
    switch(syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAIT, x, nullptr,nullptr,0))
    {case 0:
      break;
     case -1:
      switch( errno )
      { case EINTR:
         return false; // interrupted - user wants to exit?
        case EAGAIN:
          break;
        default:
          fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected futex WAIT error: %d : '%s'.",
                  errno, strerror(errno));
          return false;
       }
    }
    x = __atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_);
    } while(x < 0);
  }
  return true;
}

static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
bool mutex_unlock( register _Atomic volatile int *ua )
{ register int x;
  x = __atomic_add_fetch( ua, 1, _REL_SEQ_);
  if(x == 0) // there was ONE waiter
     while(  (1 < 
             syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, nullptr,nullptr,0)
             )
           ||(1 < __atomic_load_n(ua, _LD_SEQ_)
             ) // wait for first locker to unlock
           ) 
     { if( errno != 0 )
         switch(errno)
         {case EINTR:
           return false;
          case EAGAIN:
           break;
          default:
           fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected futex WAKE error: %d : '%s'.", 
                  errno, strerror(errno));
           return false;
         }
       }
     return true;
   }
```

So, I think if if the arithmetic operations were working as
expected, ie. were serialized and atomic, then the above
code would not deadlock; the arithmetic should be generating
the same numbers as the LockStatus enum values used in the 
working example.

But something is going wrong with the arithmetic, which now produces 
the instructions :

mutex_lock:

```
movl    $-1, %eax
lock xaddl  %eax, (%rdx)
```

mutex_unlock:

```
movl    $1, %eax
lock xaddl  %eax, (%rdx)
```

The code itself inserts no fences, but each __atomic_store_n(ua,...) generates one .

AFAICS, there is no valid schedule of that code that results
in both threads getting the same -1 value.

So my conclusion is that use of the intel LOCK prefix on arithmetic
instructions is unsafe and introduces buggy behaviour in user-mode
Linux x86_64 gcc compiled programs - only 
writes of constant values from text memory to data memory is 
atomic and sequentially ordered on Intel Haswell i7-4790M platforms
with gcc & Linux,
and arithmetic on such platforms cannot be made to be atomic & sequentially ordered by use of any combination of
HLE / XACQUIRE, lock prefix, or FENCE instructions.

My hunch is that branch prediction is somehow failing and 
adding an extra arithmetic operation / failing to perform an 
arithmetic operation on this platform with the LOCK prefix asserted
and multiple threads on different physical cores . 
Therefore, all arithmetic operations with the LOCK prefix asserted
are suspect and should be avoided.

Comment: `asm("lfence")` without a `"memory"` clobber to stop the compiler from reordering memory operations across it isn't safe.  Also, `lfence` and `sfence` have no effect on correctness if you aren't using NT stores or WC memory.  If it happens to make your code work, it's just because of the extra delay.  And BTW, the `lock` prefix on an aligned address won't cause a bus lock, just a cache-lock of that line.   IDK why you'd want to use `clflushopt` on a lock, either.  That will make it slow for no gain in correctness.  The store buffer already makes operations visible ASAP.

Comment: `ia64_has_clflush(void)` is misnamed: IA64 is Itanium.  64-bit x86 is called x86-64.  Or just call it `x86_has_clflush`.  Or better don't use it at all.

Comment: Aha! Thank you Peter ! That was probably it. So one MUST use WC memory to have any hope of true atomicity of arithmetic operations with the lock prefix?

Comment: WTF?  No, atomic ops work perfectly well on WB memory, and are most efficient that way.  Cache is coherent, so atomically updating a line in L1d makes the update atomic to all other observers in the system.  (i.e. all other cores).  [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850).  See [C & low-level semaphore implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36097001) for a counting semaphore using C11 atomics.  (Without using the futex system call, just a pure userspace implementation with no fallback to an OS sleep/wait, but shows how atomics work)

Comment: Thanks, I will review those posts. So there is no way mapping true WC memory into userspace linux process ?

Comment: I haven't done very much with HLE.  Are you asking about `lock xacquire sub`, or just `lock sub`?  It's really unclear what you're asking about, because you're talking about `lock` asserting the `#LOCK` bus signal (which isn't even a thing for addresses in DRAM on CPUs with built-in memory controllers), but then you're also using `xacquire`.  It's not surprising that `xacquire` completely changes the behaviour, because it's no longer actually doing an atomic operation, but more like attempt the transaction and then abort/commit (maybe like an LL/SC machine).  RTM is easier to understand.

Comment: I use 'ia64' to mean "Intel Core 64-bit architecture", not  Itanium. It was just a test program. I will post fully working version back when I've fully explained why two locking 'subl's can still produce the same value.

Comment: *I use 'ia64' to mean "Intel Core 64-bit architecture", not Itanium*.  Then you're wrong; don't do that :P  IA64 already has a specific technical meaning in the context of Intel CPUs.  Valid terms are Intel64, x86-64, and amd64.  Or just x86, because your function would compile and work on 32-bit x86 as well.

Comment: I did try just the plain 'lock subl ...' (__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST | __ATOMIC_HLE_ACQUIRE) 
AND the 'lock xacquire subl'  (__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)
versions, but both of them deadlock getting the same '-1'
result, which I thought from reading the docs should be
impossible - I am just trying to locate the source of my
mis-reading - thanks!

Comment: *when I've fully explained why two locking 'subl's can still produce the same value.* They can't unless you disable *actual* locking with `xacquire`.

Comment: I did try without xacquire but got same results.

Comment: Re: mapping WC memory: Apparently it is possible in user-space under Linux: [how to map memory as USWC under windows/linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/855100).  But like I said, you definitely don't want this.  Normal `lock`ed operations work efficiently on WB memory without write-back to DRAM at all, and HLE is also designed to work efficiently on user-space mutexes in WB memory.

Comment: What exactly do you deadlock on?  Is it the `futex` system call?  Are you asking about it, or are you asking about `lock sub`?   If I want a fallback to OS-assisted sleep/wake, I call `pthread_mutex_lock` or use a C++ mutex.  If I want to roll my own lockless code, I use C11 or C++11 atomics.  I haven't had to deal with a case where I needed to fall back to an OS-assisted sleep/wake in a retry loop in a lockless algo.  People have implemented such things, though, in code like liblfds: [Lock-free Progress Guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907210)

Comment: It's really hard to read your code because it's incorrectly indented, and it's so cluttered with giant `if()` blocks for instructions that should be irrelevant.  A much simpler [mcve] would be better, without any of the clflush or fence crap.

Comment: Anyway, `lock subl $1, (%rdi)` is 100% atomic even if the pointer is misaligned (but much slower in that case), and a *full* memory barrier.  If your test is finding it isn't, your hardware is broken or your test is broken.

Comment: Problem still occurs when intel_lock1.c (available at URL above) is compiled on linux with GCC 5 or 7 without either of the args '-D_WITH_CLFLUSH_' or '-D_WITH_HLE_' (so that neither CLFLUSH* nor HLE XACQUIRE are used) - the mutex_lock assembler now looks like:

# 74 "intel_lock1.c" 1
    LFENCE
    lock subl   $1, lck(%rip)
    rep nop
    SFENCE

So, I'm trying replacing {L,S}FENCE with MFENCE .

I still don't quite understand how two threads can end up with same -1 *lck value though.

Comment: See updated [ intel_lock1.c ] : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1je5lNcv7nzS802BJweM4NVUcYYIwfxQn

The updated version can be compiled with -D_NO_FENCE_ to not use any fences at all, or to use mfence with -D_MFENCE_ - still, problem occurs : both threads get -1 . The specific question I was trying to ask is 'why do two threads get the same value when both execute:
      
      'lock subl , $addr , 1'

and contents of *addr is initially 0 ? '

Comment: Your copy/paste made a mess of URLs and formatting in your comments and "answer".

Comment: I just fixed that , sorry:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1je5lNcv7nzS802BJweM4NVUcYYIwfxQn

Comment: RE: 

> If I want to roll my own lockless code, I use C11 or C++11 atomics.


but that would work only for multiple threads, not also multiple processes.
I'm trying to eventually, through refining these test cases,
get an improved lightweight locking class that works
for threads and processes if locks are in file backed 
shared memory maps.

Comment: I do have a working prototype, but that one still uses static constants instead of arithmetic - I've never been able to get a version that uses arithmetic on the mutex value to work, because of these deadlock issues that to me should
not be happening.

Comment: There is a lot to be said for _reducing_ your problem, before posting it to stack overflow, especially if you are trying to claim some type of compiler or hardware misbehavior or mis-specification. This is actually the type of question I'd be interested in, but it's just a huge mess of complex code, prose and speculation. If I understood it you are getting at some unexpected behavior with respect to locked atomic operations, but you have have also mixed in a big dose of Intel's RTM stuff. The set of people who will tackle this kind of x86-asm-and-C++-memory-ordering stuff is already ...

Comment: ... quite limited, and by throwing in the extraneous xacquire stuff, which _had nothing to do with the problem you describe_, it just cuts it down further (for example, I don't know the RTM stuff well so I wouldn't try to answer a question apparently about its intricacies). Then, on top, you add the `futex` stuff - a pretty obscure call that few people are going to know. If I understand it correctly, you've already determined that the values are "wrong" before the `futex` call so why not just cut that part out? You are entitled to ask questions how you want, but response may be limited (GIGO).

Answer (score 2):

**`lock subl $1, (%rdi)` or `lock xaddl %eax, (%rdx)` are both 100% atomic** in all cases, even if the pointer is misaligned (but much slower in that case), and are full memory barriers.  On cacheable memory, there won't be any external `#LOCK` bus signal; the internal implementation just locks the cache line in M state of MESI inside a core that's running the `lock`ed instruction.  See [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) for more details.

**If your test is finding it isn't atomic, your hardware is broken or your test is broken**.  Finding a deadlock tells you there's a bug in your design, not that your atomic primitive building-blocks aren't atomic.  You can very easily test atomic increments by using two threads to increment a shared counter, and notice that no counts are lost.  Unlike if you used `addl $1, shared(%rip)` without `lock`, where you would see lost counts.

Also, `lfence`, `sfence`, and `pause` have no effect on correctness in the normal case (no NT stores, and using only WB (Write-Back) memory).  If any of your fence / clflush stuff is helping, it's only by adding an extra delay somewhere that is maybe making that thread always lose a race in your test, not actually making it safe.  `mfence` is the only fence that matters, blocking StoreLoad reordering and store-forwarding effects.  (Which is why gcc uses it as part of implementing a seq-cst store).

Get a basic version working right before you even think about messing around with HLE / transactional memory.

---

**Race condition in your first version of acquiring the lock**

`x = __atomic_sub_fetch( ua, 1, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_);`  is atomic, and only one thread's `lock sub` can change `ua` from `0` to `-1` and get `x=-1` *from there*.

But **you aren't using the `sub_fetch` result**, you're doing another load with
`while((x = __atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_CST_)) != 0)`

**So another thread can see `ua=-1` if the first thread locks and then unlocks between the `lock sub` and the load in that 2nd thread**.

The reason it's called `sub_fetch` is that it atomically returns the old value, as well as atomically modifying the value in memory.  The fact that you discard the `sub_fetch` result is why it can compile to `lock sub` at all, instead of `lock xadd` with a register holding `-1`.

(Or a smart compiler could compile it to `lock sub` and check ZF, because you can tell when the value became non-zero or negative from flags set by `lock sub`.)

---

See [C & low-level semaphore implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094115/c-low-level-semaphore-implementation/36097001#36097001) for a simple semaphore with no fallback to OS-assisted sleep/wake.  It spins on a load until we see a value greater than 0, then attempts to take the lock with C11 `fetch_add(-1)`.

But if it loses the race to another thread, it undoes the decrement.

This is probably a poor design; it's probably best to attempt the decrement with a `lock cmpxchg`, so threads that fail won't have to undo their decrement.

---

I haven't used HLE, but I assume this bug is what breaks your HLE locking as well.

You don't need SFENCE, LFENCE, or CLFLUSH[OPT] or anything.  `lock xadd` is already a full memory barrier and 100% atomic on its own, on any memory type (including WB).

You probably misread the SDM if you thought it said you should avoid WB memory for mutexes / semaphores.

---

**You also have a race window during wakeup that can lead to deadlock**

This code in `mutex_lock` looks broken / race-prone

```
x = __atomic_sub_fetch( ua, 1, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_);  // ok, fine
_mm_pause();   // you don't want a pause on the fast path.

if( x < 0 )   // just make this a while(x<0) loop
do {
   futex(..., FUTEX_WAIT, ...);

   x = __atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_CST_);        // races with lock sub in other threads.
} while(x < 0);
```

Given thread A sleeping in `futex` with `lck == -1` (if that's possible?):

- thread B unlocks, resulting in `lck == 0`, and calls futex(FUTEX_WAKE)
- thread A wakes up, futex returns while `lck` is still 0
- some other thread (B or a 3rd thread) enters `mutex_lock` and runs `__atomic_sub_fetch( ua, 1, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_);`, leaving `lck == -1`
- thread A runs `x = __atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_CST_);` at the bottom of its loop and sees `-1`

Now you have 2 threads stuck in the futex wait loop, and no thread actually got the mutex / entered the critical section.

---

**I think your design is broken if it depends on doing a load after futex returns**

The example in [the `futex(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) of `fwait()` shows it returning after `futex` returns, without loading again.

**`futex()` is an atomic compare-and-block operation**.  Your design changes your counter value to `-1` if one thread is waiting for the lock while a third thread tries to acquire it.  So possibly your design is ok for 2 threads, but not for 3.

It's probably a good idea to use an atomic CAS for the decrement, so you never actually change `lck` to `-1` or lower, and `futex` can stay blocked.

Then if you can count on it to only ever wake 1, then can you also trust its return value to mean you really have the lock without the race-prone separate load.  I think.

Comment: Not an answer to problems of latest code. See discussion.

Comment: To address issue raised in above comment:
`
If one thread enters mutex_lock (intel_lock2.c arithmetic using version)
and the lock value is 0, it means the other thread owns the lock, 
and the lock value becomes -1; but there is a pending increment
`
I am only focusing on getting critical sections for 1 producer and 1 consumer thread working here.
`

Comment: @"Peter Cordes" : RE: 
>o thread A wakes up, futex returns while lck is still 0
futex cannot do this, because lck value was 0 at entry ;
futex(WAIT) only returns to the waiter when its monitored
pointer has changed value and another thread does a
futex(WAKE).

Comment: @"Peter Cordes" : RE >o some other thread (B or a 3rd thread) enters mutex_lock and runs __atomic_sub_fetch( ua, 1, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_);, leaving lck == -1

Comment: @"Peter Cordes" : RE
 >o some other thread (B or a 3rd thread) enters mutex_lock and runs __atomic_sub_fetch( ua, 1, _ACQ_SEQ_CST_);, leaving lck == -1

But there is no 3rd thread !  For lck to be 0,   B in this case must be
the thread allowed to continue to its critical section,  which can only
end with it invoking unlock() . So A comes in, finds the lck value has
gone negative, and enters futex until B calls unlock and sets lck to 0 .  
There is no other thread to come in and mess up the maths here!

Comment: Somehow thread A's decrement is taking place and thread B's increment is not being seen , which would seem to me to violate the strong sequential ordering constraints and locking of the 
   __atomic_sub_fetch(ua , x, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST) or
   __atomic_add_fetch(ua, x, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST) 
operations being used.
It would be nice to be able to maintain a true waiter count in the lock value, since linux can't tell us how many waiters there are, but I don't see how given the lack of reliable atomic arithmetic operations on the Intel.

Comment: @JVD: I don't have time to look at this in detail.  I think you're right that `-1` is only possible if there's a third thread, though.  But futex is an atomic compare-and-block, so it's probably best to keep the lck value at `0` while its locked, even with multiple waiters.  Use `lock cmpxchg`.  See my update to the last section.

Comment: Something about the intel_lock2.c code is telling the processor branch predictor that 'unlock' must PRECEDE 'lock',  so that it is always trying
to run any available unlock in preference to an lock; or something about the locking arithmetic operations is making it get a prediction fundamentally wrong. When I look at strace output of intel_lock3.c,
which uses just constants without the locked arithmetic, I see the
WAITs occur before the WAKEs . but the reverse in the case of intel_lock2.c .

Comment: OK, I ammended intel_lock2.c to keep a circular log in memory of lock states and TSC values, so we can see the sequence of operations
that lead up to the deadlock:

Comment: T1: {st = LS_Lock, lv = 1, tsc = 101130538063127}
T2: {st = LS_Lock, lv = 1, tsc = 101130538073306}
T2: {st = LS_Unlock, lv = 1, tsc = 101130538073429}
T2: {st = LS_Lock,   lv = 1, tsc = 101130538073567}
T1: {st = LS_Unlock, lv = 1, tsc = 101130538074118}
T1: {st = LS_Lock,   lv = 0, tsc = 101130538084471}

Comment: So what happens is threads A (T1) and B(T2) enter lock() with the lock (lv) unlocked (lck:1), then B gets the lock (lck:0), unlocks (lck:1), and enters lock() again (lck:0), but meanwhile A has been woken, which completes and unlocks and immediately enters lock() (lck:-1) again before B had woken . I think the lock value (lv) shown in this record :  T2: {st = LS_Lock, lv = 1, tsc = 101130538073567} should have been 0, OR should have been 0  here : T1: {st = LS_Unlock, lv = 1, tsc = 101130538074118}.
If the arithmetic was behaving as expected. one or the other should have happened.

Comment: @JVD: Are you still reading the lock value with a separate `__atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_);`?  That gives the other thread time to modify it again after the futex or `lock xadd` or whatever finishes.  (Sorry if that isn't helpful, I haven't been following your code changes.  I'd suggest writing down on paper (or in a text file like [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/27807118)) possible orderings of operations between the two threads.  seq-cst means there's no reordering within a thread, but ops from separate threads can reorder. Interleave in different ways to look for an order that explains your data

Answer (score -2):

The latest example intel_lock2.c program at

: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10yLrohdKLZT4p3G1icFHdjF5eHY68Yws

now works as well as the latest intel_lock3.c program at

: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ElB0qmwcDMxy9NBYkSXVxljj5djITYxa

and there is now a version that keeps an accurate negative waiter
count, and which uses locked arithmetic, at:

intel_lock4.c: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kNOppMtobNHU0lfkfWTh8auXvRcbZfhO

The unlock_mutex() routine, IFF there are waiters, must wait for each
existing waiter to unlock, so that when it returns, the mutex is 
unlocked and there are no waiters. It can either achieve this through
spin-locking + sched_yield() waiting for the lock value to become 1,
or it can use another futex call. So the original locker, when it
enters mutex_unlock(), becomes responsible for ensuring that every
existing waiter wakes up and unlocks the mutex.

Previously this answer contained:

> But there is still weirdness : if either process is ptrace-ed() by 
>   strace or compiled with '-g3' instead of '-O3', it now experiences 
>   an 'Inconsistency' -
>   ie. inconsistent critical section modified values. This does not occur
>   if the program is not ptrace-d and compiled with -O3 .

See discussion below. In order for GCC's builtin `__atomic*` functions
to work, GCC's optimization phases must be invoked, with ANY `-O$x` flag
specified during compilation sufficing to enable correct operation
of the `__atomic*` builtins.

Final best version of the mutex_lock() / unlock routines:

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
bool mutex_lock( register _Atomic volatile int *ua )
// lock the mutex value pointed to by 'ua';
// can return false if operation was interrupted ( a signal received ).
{ register int x;
  // lock_again:
  x = __atomic_add_fetch( ua, -1, _ACQ_SEQ_);
  while( x < 0 )
  { switch(syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAIT, x, nullptr,nullptr,0))
    {case 0:
      break;
     case -1:
      switch( errno )
      { case EINTR:
         return false;
        case EAGAIN:
          break;
        default:
          // this has never been observed to happen, but in any 
          // production implementation
          // should be replaced by some kind of 
          // 'throw( exception )' statement:
          fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected futex WAIT error: %d : '%s'.",
                  errno, strerror(errno));
          return false;
       }
    }
    x = __atomic_load_n(ua,_LD_SEQ_);
  }
  return true;
}

static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
bool mutex_unlock( register _Atomic volatile int *ua )
// unlock: returns false only if interrupted, else returns true
// only when the mutex pointed to by *ua has been unlocked and 
// has no waiters.
{
#ifdef _WITH_UWAIT_
  static int has_unlock_waiter = 0;
#endif
  register int x;
  x = __atomic_add_fetch( ua, 1, _REL_SEQ_);
  if(x < 1) // there was at least ONE waiter, 
            // so we are the original locker
  { while(1 < syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, nullptr,nullptr,0))
    { if( errno != 0 )
        switch(errno)
        {case EINTR:
          return false;
         case EAGAIN:
          break;
         default:
           // never observed to happen - should be a throw()
          fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected futex WAKE error: %d : '%s'.", 
                  errno, strerror(errno));
          return false;
        }
    }
#ifdef _WITH_UWAIT_
// this is strictly unnecessary, and can be replaced by use of
// sched_yield() (see below), but it
// makes the situation clearer:
// unlock :
    // so we have woken a waiter; wait for that waiter to 
    // actually unlock before returning -
    // by definition, when that waiter enters mutex_unlock() 
    // (AND IT MUST!!), it will not
    // enter the clause containing this code unless there is more than
    // one other waiter., in which case we want to continue until there
    // are no waiters.
    while(1 > (x = __atomic_load_n( ua, _LD_SEQ_ )))
    { __atomic_store_n(&has_unlock_waiter, 1, _ST_SEQ_);
      if( (-1 == 
          syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAIT, x, nullptr,nullptr,0)
          ) && (errno == EINTR)
        ) return false;
    }
    if( __atomic_load_n(&has_unlock_waiter, _ST_SEQ_) )
      __atomic_store_n(&has_unlock_waiter, 0, _ST_SEQ_);
#else
// The same result is actually achieved by this loop:
    while(1 > (x = __atomic_load_n(ua, _LD_SEQ_)))
      sched_yield();
#endif
    // we do need to wait for the waiting locker to unlock 
    // before proceeding, else
    // mutex_lock could be reentered with lck < 0 and deadlock 
    // would result.
#ifdef _WITH_UWAIT_
  }else if( (x==1) && __atomic_load_n(&has_unlock_waiter, _ST_SEQ_) )
  { // so we're the waiter that a previous unlock woke up 
    // and is waiting for - it now needs to be woken:
    while(1 < syscall( SYS_futex, ua, FUTEX_WAKE, 1, nullptr,nullptr,0))
    { if( errno != 0 )
        switch(errno)
        {case EINTR:  // no, we cannot let user try to unlock again, since modification of lock value succeeded.
         case EAGAIN:
          break;
         default:
          fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected futex WAKE error: %d : '%s'.", errno, strerror(errno));
          return false;
        }
    }
  }
#else
  }
#endif
  return true;
}
```

Testing:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu11 -pthread -D_WITH_UWAIT_ -O3 -o il2 il2.c
$ ./il2
^C20906015
$ gcc -std=gnu11 -pthread -O3 -o il2 il2.c
$ ./il2
^C45851541
```

('^C' means pressing + keys simultaneously).

Now all versions never deadlock and do work with :

```
$ strace -f -e trace=futex ./{intel_lock2 OR intel_lock3 OR intel_lock4}
```

I was trying to strace a '-g' (only) compiled version and got an Inconsistency - this does not happen if ANY '-O' flag also used.

Comment: If you need to call `sched_yield` after unlocking to avoid race conditions, your code isn't truly safe.  It just makes it harder to find the bugs by almost always hiding the race, at least when the system is not heavily.

Comment: Absolutely, but it points to the cause of the issue: somehow the combination of the locked arithmetic and the 'mfence'-es inserted by the compiler around the atomic stores of the exit condition variable is causing the processor to believe that an unlock must always "happen before" a lock, so that unlock ends up hogging the CPU and lock doesn't get scheduled. But at least I'm seeing the same problem with both versions now. I'm more interested now  in the fact that no version is  mutually 
exclusive without being compiled with -O3 ; if -gX compiled, mutual
exclusion is not achieved.

Comment: You can compile with `-O3 -g`.  Adding debug metadata is not mutually exclusive with optimization.  (You sometimes see "optimized out" when trying to examine local variables, or see a stale value for a global, when debugging optimized code, though, because debug info can't track variables when they're in registers.)

Comment: Yes, sorry, to be more precise, in order for either example to achieve mutual exclusion, (not exit with "Inconsistency!" msg), it is necessary to compile with ANY '-O' flag , regardless of any '-g' flag being also present.  ie. compilation with just '-O'  or '-O1' works with / without any '-g$X', but with any '-g$X' flag, a '-O${x}' flag MUST be specified for mutual exclusion to be achieved. After all, the gcc __atomic_* builtins seem to affect primarily the optimization phases, and if none are run, I guess their special features are disabled .

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or just an update on your investigation, or what?

Comment: @JVD: No, `_atomic` built-ins and C++11 / C11 atomics still work correctly at the default `-O0`, because `lock add` is still necessary in un-optimized code.  You keep mistrusting your tools and hardware, but it's almost certain you're just using them wrong.  Compiling without optimization probably just opens up a race window wide enough for your testing to find it consistently.

Comment: Yes, there was a bug - I was testing for rollover ( var < last_var) OUTSIDE the critical section.  In the -O or -O${x > 0}  compiled versions, this test
did not get triggered, in the -O0 compiled versions, it did. Sorry for confusion. The fixed version, which works when compiled with or without any '-O$x' flag, is at : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kNOppMtobNHU0lfkfWTh8auXvRcbZfhO

Comment: @BeeOnRope: both.